# Microsoft Teams SDK does not run getContext callback on mobile (android) but does on desktop

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am developing a Configurable Tab to be used for meetings.  I need to call getContext in order to retrieve the meetingId so that I know which meeting the tab is running in.  All works well on desktop - getContext calls the callback function and returns the context.  On mobile, though, the callback function is never called.

Here is the configurableTabs section of the manifest (configuration works fine without an issue):

```
  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx/teams-app/meetingConfig.html",
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "context":[
        "meetingChatTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

And here is the code calling getContext (this is from within the page loaded after configuration is saved and completed):

```
(async () => {
  'use strict';
  try {
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.getContext( async function (context) {
      document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "<br/><br/>Return from context " + JSON.stringify(context); //this is never called
      if (!!context && context.chatId) {
        meetingId = context.chatId;
        await initializeMeetingInfo();
        store.dispatch('setMeetingInfo', meetingInfo);
        initializeVue();
      } else {
        document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "<br/><br/>Unable to get meeting Id.  Context=" + JSON.stringify(context);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    document.getElementById("app").innerHTML += "<br/><br/>" + 'teams getContext error: ' + JSON.stringify(e);
  }
```

Any idea why getContext isn't calling the callback function on mobile (android Pixel 5)?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @JoeH,

You need to [build custom Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs) to [get context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) for your Microsoft Teams tab.

Please take a look at steps to create Teams App manifest using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#use-app-studio-to-update-the-app-package).

Comment: Hi @Rama-MSFT, thanks for your reply.  I built a custom Tab and it is working fine on desktop web and desktop app.  On mobile app, within the app, the getContext function never calls the callback function.

Comment: Hi @JoeH,

Could you please try the below sample code,

Script:
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', [])
       app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
           $scope.load = function () {
               microsoftTeams.initialize();
               microsoftTeams.getContext(context => {
                   alert(JSON.stringify(context));
               });
               
           }
       });

HTML:
<body ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div ng-init="load()">
        This is a sample code.
    </div>
</body>

Comment: Thanks @Rama-MSFT, I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the answer from comments to answers section.

Could you please try the below sample code,
Script:
var app = angular.module('DemoApp', []) app.controller('myController', function ($scope) { $scope.load = function () { microsoftTeams.initialize(); microsoftTeams.getContext(context => { alert(JSON.stringify(context)); }); } }); HTML:   This is a sample code.